# How to change data in the column as a header?

Tags: sql

I have written the SQL, where I am counting number of student by school and by there gender then, my current SQL code is:

```
SELECT sch.SchoolName, std.Gender, count(std.Student_SK) AS NoOfStudent
FROM dbo.Dim_Students std
INNER JOIN dbo.DIM_Schools sch ON std.CurrentSchool_BK = sch.School_BK
INNER JOIN dbo.FACT_Attendance att ON std.Student_SK = att.Student_FK AND sch.School_SK = att.School_FK
GROUP BY sch.SchoolName, std.Gender, std.CurrentStatus
HAVING std.CurrentStatus = N'Full time Student' AND (SUM(att.AttendanceCurriculumValue) / COUNT(att.AttendanceDate_FK) >= 0.1)  ORDER BY sch.SchoolName
```

The result produced by this is:

| SchoolName | Gender | NoOfStudent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| OCH | Female | 86 |
| OCH | Male | 40 |
| BHJ | Female | 78 |
| BHJ | Male | 75 |

But, I want to now have result like a pivot table which is like this:

[image]

How should I modify my current SQL script? Thanks

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: So when you tried using the SQL PIVOT, how did you get on?

Comment: This result is when we created pivot from excel sheet, now I want this type of result directly from SQL. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you should take a look at _conditional aggregation_. Use `case` _expressions_ to have female count in one column, and male count in another.

Comment: Why is std.CurrentStatus in the GROUP BY, when not in the SELECT clause?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on SQL server here is a query that you can use. Put your current query in the place of `select * from query_results`.
You may need to modify the query on other RDBMS.
See dbFiddle link below to test.

> ```
> SELECT SchoolName, sum([Male]) Male, sum([Female]) Female, sum([Male] + [Female]) Total
>   FROM (select * from query_results
>        ) AS pivotIntermediate
>  PIVOT (   SUM(NoOfStudent)
>            FOR Gender IN ([Male], [Female])
>        ) AS pivotTable
>        GROUP BY SchoolName with rollup
> ```
>
> ```
> SchoolName | Male | Female | Total
> :--------- | ---: | -----: | ----:
> BHJ        |   75 |     78 |   153
> OCH        |   40 |     86 |   126
> Totals     |  115 |    164 |   279
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=492ace8519f3a4f88eec79207fd2dbcf)*